# Separate Case Statement Results by a Comma

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, stimulsoft

We are using a sets of Case/When statements to reference as one table field. When we reference that one field in our report we would like the returned values to be comma separated. Now we could just hardcode the comma in but then if there is only one result or no remaining results we would have an extra comma which would look odd.

Current sample results: "Camera Not WorkingCamera Needs RefocusingCamera Dirty/Needs CleaningReposition Camera"

Desired results: "Camera Not Working, Camera Needs Refocusing, Camera Dirty/Needs Cleaning, Reposition Camera"

```
(CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Not Working] = 'True' THEN 'Camera Not Working' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Needs Refocusing] = 'True' THEN 'Camera Needs Refocusing' ELSE '' END  +
CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Dirty/Needs Cleaning] = 'True' THEN 'Camera Dirty/Needs Cleaning' ELSE '' END  +
CASE WHEN pgs.[Reposition Camera] = 'True' THEN 'Reposition Camera' ELSE '' END) as cameraissues,
(CASE WHEN pgs.[Network Down] = 'True' THEN 'Network Down' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN pgs.[Issue with Security Alarm Panel] = 'True' THEN 'Issue with Security Alarm Panel' ELSE '' END  +
CASE WHEN pgs.[System will not open on computer] = 'True' THEN 'System will not open on computer' ELSE '' END  +
CASE WHEN pgs.[Cameras not showing on TVs] = 'True' THEN 'Cameras not showing on TVs' ELSE '' END) as securityissues'
```

Answer (score 0):

not beautiful , but you can always add , at the beginning , so you always have one extra comma at the beginning and you remove it after you prepared your string :

```
STUFF((
    CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Not Working] = 'True' THEN ',Camera Not Working' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Needs Refocusing] = 'True' THEN ',Camera Needs Refocusing' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[Camera Dirty/Needs Cleaning] = 'True' THEN ',Camera Dirty/Needs Cleaning' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[Reposition Camera] = 'True' THEN ',Reposition Camera' ELSE '' END
), 1,1,'') as cameraissues,
STUFF((
    CASE WHEN pgs.[Network Down] = 'True' THEN ',Network Down' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[Issue with Security Alarm Panel] = 'True' THEN ',Issue with Security Alarm Panel' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[System will not open on computer] = 'True' THEN ',System will not open on computer' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN pgs.[Cameras not showing on TVs] = 'True' THEN ',Cameras not showing on TVs' ELSE '' END
), 1,1,'')  as securityissues
```

so I added a comma for each case statement and then by using `stuff` function I replace first character in the string which will be a comma `,`  with an empty character

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional final character and then do a single `replace` on it. After you have built your string using your `case` expression which results on a trailing comma, just add an additional character eg another comma so the string now has ',,' at the end.

With that in place you can wrap the entire block with a `replace((entire case epxression block + ','),',,','')`